# Regex postive condition test mystery

Tags: regex

I have a condition on a password field requiring

1. it to be between 5 and 8 characters
2. one number should be at least numeric

I'm using:

```
 (?=.*\d).{5,8}
```

Now the disturbing part is the way, positive conditonal test is used here and secondly, the dot before {}. Could anyone explain ?

Comment: What's your question now? Do you want to have the expression explained? Why not have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: "One number should be atleast numeric", what other numbers were you thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positive lookahead is an anchor: here it will match a position where what follows is an arbitrary set of characters (`.*`) followed by a digit (`\d`).

From this position on, there should be any character (`.`), 5 to 8 times (`{5,8}`).

Note that a positive lookahead, being an anchor, does **not** consume any character: this is why it works. Also note that the regex engine will always try to find the leftmost match.

And finally, the regex should also be anchored at the beginning and end (ie, `^(?=.*\d).{5,8}$`), otherwise it may match anywhere in the input: the original regex would match `joizjoeijoiu4ijojiar`, without caring for the length specified (`{5,8}`) as long as a digit is found in the input. The lookahead would match `joizjoeijoiu4`, and `.{5,8}` would match `joizjoei`.

Comment: Okay , well explained . I was  reading arbitrary characters(.*) as "any character zero or more times" . So do this basic meaning of metacharacters being conserved here  in postive lookhead ?

Comment: @fge...and i dint quite digest your example.  !

Comment: @kushal fixed one thing, in fact, unanchored, the regex would match the whole string. Remember that a regex can match _anywhere_ in the input. And metacharacters do not lose their meaning in a lookahead. Again, remember that they match a position.

Comment: @fge....now a bit more clear .  Now ,taking the above string  `joizjoeijoiu4ijojiar`  and regex as used with `^` and `$` anchors ofcourse, i am basically forcing  the regex engine to start its search from the first character i.e. `J` in this case   ? otherwise it would have started matching from anywhere in the input ....have i got it right ?

Comment: A regex will always start from the beginning of the input. If it does not find a match there, it will try at the next character, and so on, until it finds a match. As you say, the `^` will force the regex engine to match at the beginning of its input -- it cannot match anywhere else. Similarly, the `$` forces it to find the end of the input.

Comment: @fge...Frankly speaking ... I am still not able to read `(?=.*\d)`  efficiently .
.Here is how i am reading **Any character zero or more no of times followed by a single Digit (only once)** but when i tried it turns out that I was able to enter more than one digit(numeric) as input and **still** a pattern **match occurs** example---- `77877777`. So what was required in my points  is done .No doubts for sure. But i am not able to read it well enough to offer a good explanation to even myself.

Comment: It is what is called a "positive lookahead" (`(?=re)` where `re` is any regular expression). It is, as `^` is, an anchor, which means it matches a _position_ in the input but _does not consume any text_. The example here attempts to match a position after which an arbitrary set of characters is found, even 0 (`.*`), followed by one digit (`\d`). While it can match any such position in the input, its combination with `^` means that this position also must match the beginning of the input.

Comment: And anyway, there is a much more simple solution to your problem than using regexes: just check the length of the input (which must be between 5 and 8), and match it against `\d`. Done!

Comment: @fge...my point is, the code  is echoing a pattern match even if i enter more than one digit say `77778899` but my regex as i am reading it ,is of ONE digit !!

Comment: It is not one digit only! The only condition it has to satisfy it to find _at least_ one digit. Remember that a regex _never has to match the whole input_! This is why there are anchors -- to force a regex to match _positions_ instead of text.

Comment: And what if i wanted to match exactly ONE digit . How my regex wil lool like ?

Comment: It could go something like this: `^(?=\D+\d\D*$).{5,8}$`. But rather than using a lookahead, you could just check the length of the input and match against `^\D+\d\D*$`, it is easier to read and manage ;) (`\D` means "any character except a digit")